# Possible bug in rails conditional validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a form that allow me to edit an entry. I have a secondary set of attributes that must all be here if one of them have a value. I use conditional validates to do so :

```
validates_presence_of :raison_sociale,:nom_contact,
                        :prenom_contact,:telephone, 
                        if: (:nom_contact?||:raison_sociale?||
                          :prenom_contact? || :telephone?)
```

But the strange thing is, those 4 fields are not evaluated the same way! If i remove nom_contact, it save. But if i remove it and telephone, it fails.

What i observed is that it was ignoring a blank field if it was the first one in the if condition! As soon as i put prenom contact as first condition i cannot save without nom_contact, but now it's prenon_contact that is ignored!

Why does my conditions behave strangly and what can i do?

What ca i do to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the `if` validation in a proc.

["Symbol-only" conditional validation expects a symbol for the name of **a** method that will be called](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless).

You're including conditionals, which AFAIK won't work without being in a proc.

You can do *some* combinations by using an array, [as per the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#combining-validation-conditions):

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :mouse, presence: true,
                    if: ["market.retail?", :desktop?]
                    unless: Proc.new { |c| c.trackpad.present? }
end
```

But those are `and`, not `or`.

I'd probably wrap it up in a method anyway; IMO it's a bit long for an in-line block, but that's more a matter of opinion.